# Python Read URLs from File and print to file

Tags: python

I have a list of URLs in a text file from which I want to fetch the article text, author and article title. When these three elements are obtained I want them to be written to a file. So far I can read the URLs from the text file but Python only prints out the URLS and one (the final article). How can I re-write my script in order for Python to read and write every single URL and content?

I have to the following Python script (version 2.7 - Mac OS X Yosemite):

```
from newspaper import Article

f = open('text.txt', 'r') #text file containing the URLS
for line in f:
    print line

url = line
first_article = Article(url)
first_article.download()

first_article.parse()

# write/append to file 
with open('anothertest.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write(first_article.title)
    f.write(first_article.text)

print str(first_article.title)

for authors in first_article.authors:
    print authors
if not authors:
    print 'No author'

print str(first_article.text)
```

Comment: Move your article loading stuff *into* the `for line in f` loop, after all that is something that you want to do for each `line` in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the last article, because you're iterating over all the lines of the file:

```
for line in f:
    print line
```

and once the loop is over, line contains the last value.

```
url = line
```

If you move the contents of your code within the loop, so that:

```py
with open('text.txt', 'r') as f: #text file containing the URLS
    with open('anothertest.txt', 'a') as fout:
        for url in f:
            print(u"URL Line: {}".format(url.encode('utf-8')))

            # you might want to remove endlines and whitespaces from 
            # around the URL, which what strip() does
            article = Article(url.strip())
            article.download()
            article.parse()

            # write/append to file 
            fout.write(article.title)
            fout.write(article.text)

            print(u"Title: {}".format(article.title.encode('utf-8')))

            # print authors only if there are authors to show.
            if len(article.authors) == 0:
                print('No author!')
            else:
                for author in article.authors:
                    print(u"Author: {}".format(author.encode('utf-8')))

            print("Text of the article:")
            print(article.text.encode('utf-8'))
```

I also made a few changes to improve your code:

- use with open() also for reading the file, to properly release the file descriptor
  when you don't need it anymore ;
- call the output file `fout` to avoid shadowing the first file
- made the opening call for `fout` done once, before entering the loop to avoid opening/closing the file at each iteration,
- check for length of `article.authors` instead of checking for existence of `authors`
  as `authors` won't exist when you don't get within the loop because `article.authors`
  is empty.

HTH

Comment: This helps a lot but I get some error codes: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2018' in position 421: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: I left one `first_article` at the end, otherwise the code should be working fine. I simplified it a bit, and added a bit more "user friendliness" for debugging.

Comment: aaah! The infamous `UnicodeEncodeError`. There are 100s of questions about it on SO, and even more articles on internet. The easy solution: switch to python3, the hard one, use `.encode()/.decode()` where the error is.

Comment: I've added a few `encode()` for each string that could contain unicode characters, and made all the strings unicode, before printing them out to stdout. the `.write()` should go fine, though. Try that out, and read more about the encode/decode errors. N.B.: technically that's another question (which will be very likely to be marked as duplicate of 500 others).

Comment: Okay. It works for some articles but that's indeed the Unicode error. Maybe it's easy but how can I write everything to a file (so also authors and maybe date of article?) When I add 'article.publish_date' it give me a 'TypeError: expected a character buffer object' (so in this case: fout.write(article.publish_date))

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot help you there, as I don't know what the `article.publish_date` returns, or gets as parameters, and what it actually does "behind the hood". You might want to ask a separate question on that aspect.

Comment: BTW, if the answer did help you out, you can accept it, so it will give you more points and enable you more "rights" on stack overflow. And welcome, BTW. Don't hesitate to ask any other question, making them as simple and concise as you can do, with a good code example, so you can help other people help you!